# How do I recover the offline feature in YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I have lost the YouTube offline feature on my accounts and devices. The offline option has disappeared from settings. I have tried uninstalling updates and reinstalling them, I have tried changing countries, I have tried using online suggestions. Nothing has worked and the offline feature is still missing. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: "I have tried using online suggestions" If you want to get some *new* suggestions, you should tell us what you've already tried. Nobody will answer if they think you have already done what they would suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Offline videos are now only available for YouTube Red subscribers. 
[Youtube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6308116?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

As Alex said it it is feature of paid subscription, but there are a lot of other options to get it for free.

1. Root your phone and install xposed then YouTube addons from xposed framework.
2. If you do not have rooted device you can install ogYoutube which will allow you to use feature you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The OP should have also tried to clear the cache. Or check if his/her country was on the [list of countries](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6141269?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) where offline viewing was allowed. It was [restricted to 16 countries](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/03/01/youtube-updates-list-countries-support-offline-video-downloads/) (I guess that when the OP's Youtube app lost the offline feature) before being extended.

If you can still use the offline options then:

1. When watching a video that you would like to watch offline, click on Save or Download.
2. Select the video quality, then click OK.

The YouTube app will start downloading the video. The videos downloaded for offline viewing are available for 30 days (you need to connect at least once during the next 30 days to keep them offline). Note that there are still videos that you will not be able to watch offline due to copyrights, etc.